# How to get the Database Id from an XML Id

Tags: odoo

The `osv.osv` provides a `get_xml_id` method to find the XML Id for the provided Database Id.
What is the best way to do the opposite?

Knowing the XML Id (it was defined in the data loading file), how can I get the corresponding Database Id, so that I can refer to it in tour Python code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `ir_model_data` object has a `_get_id()` method that does what you're looking for. You can see it in use in [the `res_users._get_admin_id()` method](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~openerp/openobject-server/trunk/view/head:/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py?start_revid=3932#L309):

```
def _get_admin_id(self, cr):
    if self.__admin_ids.get(cr.dbname) is None:
        ir_model_data_obj = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
        mdid = ir_model_data_obj._get_id(cr, 1, 'base', 'user_root')
        self.__admin_ids[cr.dbname] = ir_model_data_obj.read(cr, 1, [mdid], ['res_id'])[0]['res_id']
    return self.__admin_ids[cr.dbname]
```

Comment: Thanks. Managed to get a single line solution working:   self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object(cr, uid, 'hr_timesheet', 'analytic_journal').id

Answer (score 10):

The `ir.model.data` model also has a `get_object()` method returning a browsable record given a model name and an xml_id.

So, another solution could be:

```
    m  = self.pool.get('ir.model.data')
    id = m.get_object(cr, uid, 'base', 'user_root').id
```